# org.freedesktop.PolicyKit.Error.Failed: ('system-bus-name', {'name': ':1.96'}): org.debian.apt.install-or-remove-packages

Tags: permissions, software-center

I'm using a Lenovo 100S Chromebook and I'm using a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 (Unity). I'm having a problem where I basically have no permissions for anything. Software Center, Software Updater. I managed to get permissions for Software Center by using:

```
sudo software-center
```

This allowed me to download Software Boutique, but when I try to install through that, I don't have permissions. I have looked everywhere and have not found a clear solution for this (although I am new to Ubuntu so maybe I just didn't understand what I read).

Also worth noting that if I use

```
sudo update-manager
```

Software update will work, but it does only through the terminal.

EDIT: When I try to install via Software Center, I get a window that says:

> AUTHENTICATION ERROR
>
> Software can't be installed or removed because the authentication service is not available. `(org.freedesktop.PolicyKit.Error.Failed: ('system-bus-name', {'name':  ':1.91'}): org.debian.apt.install-or-remove-packages`

When I hit <kbd>OK</kbd> I get another window that says

> You don't have the required permissions to perform this action

and under details it says

> `org.freedesktop.PolicyKit.Error.Failed: ('system-bus-name', {'name': ':1.96'}): org.debian.apt.install-or-remove-packages`

Comment: @zanna I edited it with the messages I get when trying to install. I get a similar message with software updater and software boutique.

Comment: I found a workaround:  Start the application like  gnome-language-selector  from the terminal using elevated rights. This means you invoke "sudo    /usr/bin/gnome-language-selector" and do your changes succesful.  No solution for the misconfiguration but a solution for your task.             I obtained the error   "org.freedesktop.PolicyKit.Error.Failed: ('system-bus-name', {'name': ':1.183'}): org.debian.apt.install-or-remove-packages    when editing the Ubuntu 20.04 Language Settings from XFCE4.